# concatLatestFrom with multiple selectors ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, nrwl-nx

I am trying to get 2 selectors with the latest concatLatestFrom that was introduced in NgRx 12, however i cant seem to understand what i am doing wrong and i am unable to achieve this.

I have an effect that looks like this

```
  loadAllCases$ = createEffect(() => this._actions$.pipe(
    concatLatestFrom(() => [
      this.store.pipe(select(CaseSelectors.getAllCases)),
      this.store.pipe(select(CaseSelectors.getCasesLoaded))
    ]),
    navigation(this.caseLandingPage, {
      run: (snap, [loaded, cases]) => {
        if (loaded) {
          return CaseActions.loadAllSuccess();
        } else {
          return this._caseService.getAll().pipe(
            map(cases => CaseActions.loadAllSuccess(cases))
          );
        }
      },
      onError: (action, error) => {
        return CaseActions.loadAllFailed(error);
      }
    })
  ));
```

However this doesnt seem to work due to type incompatibility

```
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Action, [Action, boolean, Case[]]>' is not assignable to 
parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Action, ActionOrActionWithState<unknown, Action>>'. 
Type '[Action, boolean, Case[]]' is not assignable to type 'ActionOrActionWithState<unknown,
Action>'.
Type '[Action, boolean, Case[]]' is not assignable to type '[Action, unknown]'.       
Source has 3 element(s) but target allows only 2
```

However. if i just leave one selector this works fine, is this a case that using concatLatestFrom can only select one selector?
Note i have tried chaining them one after the other this produces the same error. Any help or advice appretiated.

### Update

This appears to be Nx specific bug, and the navigation pipe it providers, i have oppened a bug related issue with the Nx Repository https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/6830

The code in the example works fine if it is piped with any RxJs operation.

Comment: The Nx bug has been fixed- https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/8216

Answer (score 13):

There is a type declaration for the concatLatestFrom function and its overloaded version

```typescript
import { Observable, ObservedValueOf, OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs';
export declare function concatLatestFrom<T extends Observable<unknown>[], V>(observablesFactory: (value: V) => [...T]): OperatorFunction<V, [V, ...{
    [i in keyof T]: ObservedValueOf<T[i]>;
}]>;
export declare function concatLatestFrom<T extends Observable<unknown>, V>(observableFactory: (value: V) => T): OperatorFunction<V, [V, ObservedValueOf<T>]>;
```

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/12.4.0/modules/effects/src/concat_latest_from.ts

So you're right this function accepts either a single observable or an array of observables.

But it seems you're using order of operators in a wrong way

*I'm not sure what does **navigation** and **caseLandingPage** mean, but this example might give you an idea of how to fix/improve your effect handler*

```typescript
public readonly something$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(someAction),
        concatLatestFrom(() => [
          this.store.select(selectFoo),
          this.store.select(selectBar),
        ]),
        switchMap(([action, foo, bar]) => {

          // Do what you need

        }),
      ),
  );
```

Comment: Hi Anthon apologies i forgot to update that this is an Nx issue with the navigation pipe rather than with rxjs. The format i have in my question works fine if its piped with any rxjs operators. I will update that a bug reported has been oppened with the nx library

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm, the types accept an array of selectors and there's also [a test](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/0bb49409413b784b1cc55c2b59e67ed760041aa5/modules/effects/spec/concat_latest_from.spec.ts#L87) to verify that it works.

Do you have a runnable reproduction?
The problem will probably be something else.

The error itself mentions the correct types returned by `concatLatestFrom`, so my guess would be that the `navigate` operator needs to be tweaked.

```
Type '[Action, boolean, Case[]]' is not assignable ...
```

Comment: I hve decided to upvote this but not sure if it should be marked as correct, this works if i use map that is true so it is an issue with navigate thus making this answer correct. However i would like to leave this open in case someone has a workaround,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the pipe functions, like this:

```
   concatLatestFrom(() => [
      this.store.select(CaseSelectors.getAllCases),
      this.store.select(CaseSelectors.getCasesLoaded)
    ]),
```